# Find all possible lines based on one point using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

So, I have an equation in this format:

$$y = \frac{bx + cK}{a+b+c},$$

where $a,b,c$ and $K$ are constants.

I'm trying to, given one point, find $a$, $b$ and $c$ that describes all the possibles lines that crosses that point.

I know that I can just calculate like this (for the point $(-5,0)$ and $K=12$, for example):

$$0 = \frac{-5b + 12c}{a+b+c}$$

$$b = \frac{12c}{5}$$

But I'm trying to write a script to do this, so a matricial solution would be useful.

I've tried to write the equation like this:

$$b(x-y) + c(K-y) - ay = 0$$

and I think the solution may be something related with the null space of the matrix, but don't understand how I can do this.